# Facebook Graph Search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Facebook's graph search is indeed a great way to find people with certain interests, activities, etc.

However, some queries that work well within Facebook's search interface have failed with the API.

Those queries include: 
- People who like tennis.
- People who checked in at Heathrow Airport.
- People who work at Facebook.

This is how I wrote the query:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=people+who+like+tennis&type=user

I want to return all the user objects that match the query "people who like tennis".

Is this possible or is the Graph API just limited to simple one word queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible with the Graph API search. Have a look at

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search

to see what is possible concerning Graph API search.

Answer (score 0):

Graph Search that you use on Facebook.com and the Graph API search that you use using the API are two completely different things. There are no API for Graph Search.